# How to prevent time difference in timer in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, timer, stopwatch

I used 2 timer(`timer1` and `timer2`) and 1 stopwatch(`watch`) in my windows form application. When `timer1` finished it works `watch` is stopped and `timer2` started to work. My problem is: stopping time of the `watch` in `timer1` is not equal to the inital value of the `watch` in `timer2`.Interval values of the timers are equal and it is 25 ms. How can prevent this time difference between `watch` start and stop values in timers? Here is my code;

```
    Stopwatch watch=new Stopwatch();

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       watch.Start();
      var time = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

     .
     .
     .
      watch.stop();
     }
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      watch.Start();
      var time = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

     .
     .
     .
      watch.stop();
     }
```

Comment: Since the code is run sequentially I do not think you could ever get it to be precise. Do you know how long the timer will/should run for?

Comment: Max 15 seconds.

Comment: alright, what I was going for was whether or not you could kinda predict the amount of time it would run for

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I trying to do get velocity values from GPS. So there are some if conditions(I didn't write above because to keep code simple) which decide to work timer1 and timer2. For example timer1 works for acceleration and timer2 works for deceleration. Therefore, to calculate total time in acceleration and deceleration I created 2 timer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't get actually equal times of starting and stopping - there is processing time between them.
Next, according to docs for Windows.Forms.Timer:

> The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds. If you require a multithreaded timer with greater accuracy, use the Timer class in the System.Timers namespace.

([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx))

So your timer values are below the accuracy.

I think, the only way for you to work this out is to put all the code in one timer, so the timer2 actions will be done right after timer1 actions.

Edit: since you didn't say what was the timer, i assumed that was WinForms timer. Sorry if i was wrong.

Comment: Yes, NaviE. I used Winforms timer and thank you for accuracy information. I didn't know that.